# In Mac, Selenium WebDriver is launching the browser successfully but is not opening by itself

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser, selenium-chromedriver

The driver path is correct and hence a new chrome browser was **launched successfully** and ran the actions as per the code. However, i could not see those actions, because the newly launched chrome browser is **not opening by itself**. So i need to click on the browser manually to see the actions going on in browser. Tried with chrome and Firefox in **Mac**. **How will the browser opens by itself?** Here is the code which i tried

```
package trial;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Classname 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/usr/local/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        }
}
```

Here is the console logs

Starting ChromeDriver 2.36.540469 (1881fd7f8641508feb5166b7cae561d87723cfa8) on port 28190
Only local connections are allowed.
May 03, 2018 11:49:00 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

Comment: Update the question with the console logs please

Comment: restart your machine and manually launch chrome browser and then close it , then run your code !

Comment: @DebanjanB Updated the console logs

Comment: @cruisepandey Tried doing that but still its not opening by itself

Comment: @RufusBenny `INFO: Detected dialect: OSS` implies all is well. Update the question with the binary versions you are using i.e. _Selenium Client_ / _WebDriver_ / _WebClient_ variant and versions please.